# Помогите решить проблему с AutoSuggestBox

Tags: c#, .net

У меня поле в котором происходит выбор страны. Я хочу сделать так, чтобы если написали несуществующую страну и перешли к другому полю оно очищалось. Сделал это так:

```
private void Countrybox_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var term = CountryBox.Text.ToLower();
    var results = Countries.Where(i => i.ToLower().Contains(term)).ToList();
    if (results.Count != 1)
    {
        CountryBox.Text = "";
    }
    else if (results.Count == 1)
    {
        CountryBox.Text = results[0];
    }
}
```

Но, например, если ввел первую букву(и список из 20 стран сократился до 10) и после этого мышкой выбрал страну, он очищает поле и список становиться снова 20, как будто я ничего не выбирал. Я так понимаю, что он сначала переходит в событие "LostFocus" и только потом создает текст который я выбрал из списка. Помогите пожалуйста, сам пока никак не могу дойти до решения этой проблемки...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мне помогло добавление события SuggestionChosen.

```
private void CountryBox_Chosen(AutoSuggestBox sender, AutoSuggestBoxSuggestionChosenEventArgs args)
    {
        CountryBox.Text = args.SelectedItem as string;
    }
```